# In SwiftUI how can I bold the primaryAction ToolbarItem?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

How can I get the ToolbarItem to bold the primaryAction?  I have been able to change the color by setting the accent color on the NavigationView. Primarily looking for a SwiftUI solution but I will settle for UI Kit solution if not possible. My Code:

```
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.primaryAction) {
    Button(action: { }) {
      Text("Save")
        .fontWeight(.black) // does nothing
        .bold() // does nothing
    }
  }
}
```

primaryAction placement is not bolded:

[image: primaryAction placement is not bolded]

principal placement is bolded by default:

[image: principal placement is bolded by default]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I struggled with this one for a while too. The solution is to use `.confirmationAction` instead of `.primaryAction`. This renders in the same location but with bold text, at least for now (on iOS 14).

```
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement.confirmationAction) {
    Button {
      //do something
    } label: {
      Text("Save")
    }
  }
}
```